# XCode - when it comes to UiWebView there is an issue

Tags: xcode, uiwebview

I'm totally new when it comes to xcode, but there occured a problem:

I'm designing an iPad-App(Retina Display) in html/css with the standard retina resolution of 2048x1536px...the problem is, that when I open the app on the pad, the page turns out to be way too huge. If I'm reading out the UiWebView-Resolution I get 1024x768...am I able to change this to get the real iPad dimension?

thx for your help!

Best regards,
daft

Answer (score 1):

Dimension values on iOS are described in points. Each point can have different number of pixels - depends on screen's pixel density. UIWebView interprets html document size value as point - so 1 html pixel means 1 point. 

I suggest you two options to cope with that:
1. Design you're web app to resolution 1024x768 and insert images which are scaled to 50% size to have more pixel density.
2. Leave page in 2048x1536 resolution and use UIWebView api to scale content.

Comment: so when 1pt = 1px then should 2048x1536pt = 2048x1536, right? So with a retina display which knows 2048x1536 it should be able to get the real dimensions by replacing px with pt?

Comment: There was quite few web pages before retina came into play. If UIWebView would automatically scale all of those pages depending on screen's pixel density that could be a horror for web developers.

Comment: So am I not able to set UIWebView to use 2048x1536px instead of 1024x768px? Can't I set this in xCode to just use the right resolution?